# Change each line of text to each column of csv file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file. For example

```
 This is computer
 That one is monitor
 Some products are printer
```

I want to save each line of data into each column of csv file as a one row.

[image: expected result]

So, I try to create a batch file like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file=a.txt
set content=
echo %file%
for /F  %%i in (a.txt) Do (
        set content=!content!,%%i
    )
echo %content%>>result.csv
pause
```

But I get only the first word from every line of text.

[image: result]

When I try to add `tokens=*` to for loop,

```
for /F "tokens=*"  %%i in (a.txt) Do....
```

I got the error: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

I'm not understand whats wrong with my code and I'm not familiar with batch script.

Comment: Due to potential line/variable length and character limitations, we really need to see a better representative sample of your input text file. A likely culprit for the `cannot find the file` error message will be the **`<`** character; _e.g. `>>"result.txt" Echo(MyLineOne,My<Line>Two,MyLineThree`_. Try it and you'll see the message you reported. Now remove the **`<`** and try it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your protecting spaces in your line content and file names:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "fIn=a.txt"
Set "fOut=result.csv"
Set "str="
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%fIn%") Do Set "str=!str!,%%A"
If Defined str >>"%fOut%" Echo(%str:~1%
```

**Edit**

A slight alternative to cater for some potential problematic characters which may exist in the not provided content of the file:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "fIn=a.txt"
Set "fOut=result.csv"
Set "str="
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%fIn%") Do Set "str=!str!,%%A"
EndLocal & Set/P "=%str:~1%"<Nul>>"%fOut%"
```

Comment: Nothing write into csv file.

Comment: @Cloud, and downvoter …the script works exactly as intended using exactly the data you provided in your question! If your question data didn't properly represent your data then that's not my fault!

Comment: Compo's code works fine for me as well as mine (see my solution). Still, both solutions don't work for you. I guess the error might be in the input file?!

Comment: I have edited my answer with an alternative piece of code, to possibly help with problematic characters in your input file content.

Comment: Thank you so much @Compo. Now, your edited code is work. One more thing is, if I want to add file name (`a.txt`) to first column of csv, how can I do that? When I try to add file name to `Set "str=%fIn%"`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide the proper content of the file and I'll consider it!

Answer (score 0):

There were several bugs in your code. I've fixed them so now a proper csv string is being generated. However, newer Excel versions actually use **;** instead of **,** to separate cells. This is your code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set file=a.txt
for /F %%i in (%file%) Do (
        set content=!content!;%%i
    )
set content=!content:~1!
echo %content%>>result.csv
pause
```

Comment: It just only output `This | That | Some` in csv file.

Comment: Please post the content of "a.txt".

Comment: @Cloud is correct, your script can only output the first token with the default delimiters. To fix it you need to use one of either `"Tokens=*"` or `"Delims="`. That said it makes little difference at the moment because the all important `a.txt` content still remains a mystery.